# UIScrollView has large contentSize but doesn't scroll - no autoLayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

In my Swift 2 iOS 9.0 project I've set up a UIScrollView with a UIImageView and some buttons and labels. For some other reasons the scrollView's frame is 652 points wide and 652 points high. Its content is decided by the image in the imageView (it's 1000x1000):

```
func loadImageOntoView(FloorImage:UIImage) -> Void {

mapImageView.image = FloorImage
    // containerView is my root view, same size as the screen
    let cw = containerView.frame.width
    let ch = containerView.frame.height
    let cd = sqrt(cw*cw + ch*ch)

    /* Here I set scrollView's frame to be a square with sides as 
    long as containerView's diagonal. This makes sure that if the scrollView
    is rotated it's always bigger than the screen*/
    scrollView.frame = CGRect(
        x: -(cd-cw)/2, y: -(cd-ch)/2,
        width: cd, height: cd
    )
    scrollView.contentSize = FloorImage.size

    //Here it centers the imageView in the scrollView
    mapImageView.center = CGPoint(
        x: scrollView.frame.size.width/2, y: scrollView.frame.size.height/2)

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.9
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 15.1
}
```

I'm not completely sure on these scrollViews, but I thought it was supposed to be able to scroll with these settings? When I zoom in I can scroll, but when the zoomScale = 1 it doesn't work. What have I done wrong, or how should I go about using scrollViews?

Comment: Is scrolling enabled?  And why aren't you using autolayout in 2016?

Comment: This code has [some readability issues](http://importblogkit.com/2015/03/writing-readable-code/).

Comment: @nhgrif Scrolling is enabled. I'm not using autolayout because I find it kind of hard to work with and this just works better for me, do you think it's very important to use it? Excuses about the readability issues, I'll try and fix it. Also, I've now solved it by disabling scrolling and moving everything inside the scrollView with a drag gesture but I'm not very happy with this solution.